# Is there a name for this simple structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Is there a name for $(X,S)$ where $X$ is a set and $S\subseteq X$ and a morphism $(X,S)\overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}(X^\prime,S^\prime)$ is a function $\alpha:X\rightarrow X^\prime$ such that $x\in S\implies \alpha(x)\in S^\prime$?

I find this structure interesting since a lot of mathematical structures can be expressed this way.

Comment: I know that pairs of spaces are used in algebraic topology, and I have discovered for myself that the category of Clifford algebras (or exterior algebras if you prefer) is governed by this pairing picture. I suppose you can also consider the category of field extensions an example (where $\alpha$ is an isomorphism of fields). What other examples did you find? I'm interested...

Comment: @rschwieb: My point of view on this is somewhat philosophical. I have included examples in my profile: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/171248/lehs?tab=profile

Answer (score 3):

If the sets have a topology, it's a [*pair of space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_spaces).  So you could call your sets is a *pair of sets*. The category you describe is sometimes described as the relative category of sets.  I know no name for it, I would call it $\texttt{RelSet}$.

If the subset is always a single point (i.e. a singleton), it's called a *pointed set* and the category is denoted by $\texttt{Set}^*$.

Comment: Pair of sets harmonize with pair of spaces but make me think of any pair of sets. An analogy to pointed sets is spotted sets. But it would be nice know if someone has named it before.

Comment: Sorry, I'm seeing this comment probably too late, but to be more precise you could call it an *ordered pair of spaces*, implying the other given by $\subseteq$.  Not to be confused with a pair of ordered spaces.